# Converting Year-month character to YYYY-MM date in R

Tags: r, date

I have trouble converting a character column with YYYY-MM format to date types in R. I have already tried different approaches to address this but none worked.

```
    dateC = "2001-01"
    # Method I)
    dateF <- as.factor(dateC) # returns factor: "2001-1"
    dateD <- as.Date(dateF,format="%Y-%m") # returns NA
    # Method II) 
    dateI <- as.double(dateC) # returns NA
    dateD <- as.Date(dateI,format="%Y-%m") # returns NA
```

The method I) works when the character column is in YYYY-MM-DD format, however not for year and month ones.

Method II) is not working for either of the formats. I somehow managed to change the characters to integer (with some random function that I do not remember now!) and then applied as.date() but that did not work either.

Comment: A date object contains a year, month and day.  Try: `as.Date(paste(dateF, 1) , format="%Y-%m %d")`, this will set every conversion to the first of the month.

Comment: It does and it worked! Thanks! So based on what you said, R does not recognize year-month is as a date object, right? There has to be a "day" element too. Am I right?

Comment: Yes correct!  A date has to have a day, month and year.

Comment: Agree.  I got a column with 2020-03  which is YYYY-MM format.
When importing, R reads it as a character. 
So i can do these two steps in one formula but let me break down into two steps:
# this is to add the day behind the YYYY-mm
step 1. Data$Date2 <- paste0(Data$date, "-1")
#this follows the format of the character (given in hyphens) so it converts accordingly
step 2. Data$Date3 <- as.Date(Data$Date2, "%Y-%m-%d")